# knockout: dorp down list not populated from json

Tags: knockout.js

I am collecting a list of property types from my server in json and I cannot seem to populate the drop down list.
The following code includes some commented out hard coding which also does not work.
In developer tools the correct number of options are created, but the text and values are not set.

knockout code:

```
var self;
var propertyTypes;
var NewBuildViewModel = function () {
    self = this;
    self.enteredBlockUprn = ko.observable("");
    self.showForm = ko.observable(false);
    self.PropertyTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
    //var temp = GetHiddenField("sir-property-types");
    var temp1 = ([
        {
            PropertyTypeId: 1,
            Type: "Maisonette"
        },

        {
            PropertyTypeId: 2,
            Type: "House"
        },
        {
            PropertyTypeId: 3,
            Type: "Flat"
        }
    ]);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(temp1, {}, self.PropertyTypes);
    self.selectedPropertyType = ko.observable("");
    self.getNewBuildDetails = function () {
        var enteredUprn = this.enteredBlockUprn();
        if (enteredUprn.length > 0) {
            getNewBuildFromBlockUPRN(enteredUprn);
        }
    };
};

var displayNewBuild = function (data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(json, {}, self);
    self.showForm(true);
};

var getNewBuildFromBlockUPRN = function (blockUPRN) {
    var url = GetHiddenField("sir-get-new-build-url").replace("@", blockUPRN);
    var callback = displayNewBuild;
    var errorCallback = errorMessage;
    dataService.getItem1(url, callback, errorCallback);
};

@using Newtonsoft.Json
@model NewBuildBlockViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add/Edit New Build Properties";
    ViewBag.GetNewBuildUrl = "/api/newbuild/@/getnewbuildbyuprn".ToServer();
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SessionObjectSir.PropertyTypes);
}
<div id="hiddenFields"
     data-sir-get-new-build-url="@ViewBag.GetNewBuildUrl"
     data-sir-property-types="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SessionObjectSir.PropertyTypes)"></div>
<fieldset>
    <legend>@ViewBag.Title</legend>
    <section id="sectionEnterBlockUPRN">
        <div id="divEnterBlockUPRN">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    Add/Edit Property for Block UPRN:
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: enteredBlockUprn" id="EnteredBlockUprn" />
                    <input type="button"
                           data-bind="click: getNewBuildDetails"
                           id="btnAddEdit"
                           class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                           value="Add/Edit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="sectionEnterNewBuildDetails" data-bind="if: showForm" style="background-color: whitesmoke;" class="container">
        <div id="divEnterNewBuildDetails">
            <h4>Enter New Build</h4>

            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right"><label for="PropertyTypes">Property Type:</label></div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: left">
                    <select data-bind="options: 'PropertyTypes', optionsText: 'Type', optionsValue: 'PropertyTypeId', value: selectedPropertyType, optionsCaption: '<-- Select Property Type -->'"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p><button id="newBuildSave" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Save</button></p>
        </div>
    </section>
</fieldset>

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/sir/addeditnewbuildproperty")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var newBuildViewModel = new NewBuildViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(newBuildViewModel);
    </script>
}
```

So how do I fix this?

Comment: Please reduce your code to only include those parts which are essential for reproducing the problem.

Comment: Still: Wall of code.

Comment: OK I have cut down the code. I am just a bit concerned I might remove something that I should not have done.

Comment: I don't see how `@using Newtonsoft.Json
@model NewBuildBlockViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add/Edit New Build Properties";
    ViewBag.GetNewBuildUrl = "/api/newbuild/@/getnewbuildbyuprn".ToServer();
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SessionObjectSir.PropertyTypes);
}` is related to Knockout.js. Can you please remove all non-related, server-side code?

Comment: It looks like the var "self" is a global variable. Is that correct or is there more of the view-model that isn't shown?

Comment: Yes, self was a global variable but I have now changed that and included the 2 functions within the view model so that I do not have to do that. I appreciate global variables are generally bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while to dig through all of that code, but the error eventually revealed itself. Your select binding is binding to the string 'PropertyTypes' instead of to the observable array `PropertyTypes`. You just need to remove the quotes around that binding target.

```
<select data-bind="options: PropertyTypes, ...
```

repro:

```js
var self;
var propertyTypes;
var NewBuildViewModel = function (data) {
    self = this;
    self.enteredBlockUprn = ko.observable("");
    self.showForm = ko.observable(false);
    self.PropertyTypes = ko.observableArray([]);

    var temp1 = ([ { PropertyTypeId: 1, Type: "Maisonette" },  { PropertyTypeId: 2, Type: "House" }, { PropertyTypeId: 3, Type: "Flat" } ]); 
    ko.mapping.fromJS(temp1, {}, self.PropertyTypes);
    self.selectedPropertyType = ko.observable("");
    self.getNewBuildDetails = function () {
        var enteredUprn = this.enteredBlockUprn();
        if (enteredUprn.length > 0) {
            //getNewBuildFromBlockUPRN(enteredUprn);
        }
    };
    
    self.showForm(true); //added for debugging
};

ko.applyBindings(new NewBuildViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: left">
                    <select data-bind="options: PropertyTypes, optionsText: 'Type', optionsValue: 'PropertyTypeId', value: selectedPropertyType, optionsCaption: '<-- Select Property Type -->'"></select>
                </div>
<br/><br/>

<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(PropertyTypes)"></span>
<br/><br/>

<span data-bind="text: 'Selected: ' + ko.toJSON(selectedPropertyType)"></span>
```

Comment: Apologies I had to go home before I could edit the question any further. And thank you very much for your answer. Sometimes you have to learn syntax the hard way, I can see why it makes sense the way it is but it is such a fine detail and no help with intellisense or error messages.